# Implementing bubble sort to File Processing in C

Tags: c, file, bubble-sort

We're learning on File Processing today where we store the scores the user inputted. I got the File Processing part covered but I'm having a hard time arranging the scores in descending order. I'm thinking of using bubble sort but I don't know where to put it since we're still fairly new to the topic of File Processing. Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX 100

int main(){
FILE *myPtr;
int score=0, choice;
char name[MAX]="";

while (choice != 3) {
    printf("What do you want to do?\n");
    printf("\t1 - Enter new score\n");
    printf("\t2 - View all scores\n");
    printf("Choice: ");
    scanf("%d", &choice);
    switch (choice){
        case 1:
            printf("Enter name: ");
            scanf("%s", name);
            printf("Enter score: ");
            scanf("%d", &score);
            if ((myPtr = fopen("topscores.txt", "a")) == NULL)
                printf("File could not be opened. :(\n");
            else {
                fprintf(myPtr, "Name:\t%s", name);
                fprintf(myPtr, "Score:\t%d", score);
                fclose(myPtr);
                printf("Score added successfully!\n");
                system("pause");
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            system("cls");
            printf("TOP 10 SCORES:\n\n");
            if ((myPtr = fopen("topscores.txt", "r") )== NULL)
                printf("File could not be opened. :(\n");
            else {
                printf("NAME\tSCORE\n\n");
                fscanf(myPtr, "%s%d", name, &score);
                while (!feof(myPtr)){
                    printf("%s\t%d\n", name, score);
                    fscanf(myPtr, "%s%d", name, &score);
                }
                fclose(myPtr);
                printf("\n");
                system("pause");
            }
            break;
```

Do I put the bubble sort in case 2 or case 1? Help, please.

Comment: Probably best to put it in case (2), since if you put it in case (1) you'd have to re-sort the file every time you appended an item to the file, and that would be inefficient.  Note that in the case (2) section you'll need to first load all the items in the file into an in-memory data structure, then sort the data structure, then iterate over the data structure to print the sorted results.

Comment: Format of the input and the output is different.、